# Remove dependencies from Package.json and Node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm

After Removing a list of dependency from package.json file, I want to remove them from the node_modules directory using some command with out having to specify every package name again.

Comment: Remove the whole `node_modules` directory, then `npm install` again? Normally this doesn't matter. Extraneous packages in there rarely take up a lot of space, nor take too long to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm update` after removing the entries from your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Try the [npm-prune](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) command. Also [npm-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-clean) might be usefull